# Capitalized React Element throws Element type is invalid -- why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create custom tags with React, like so:

```
// imports

// react
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// ========================================

// classes & functions

const Home = <Home></Home>;

// ========================================

// exports

ReactDOM.render(
  Home,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

`<Home></Home>` throws the error `Element type is invalid`.

Changing this to `<home></home` will work and will render this element in the browser, but I get this flag:

> index.js:2178 Warning: The tag  is unrecognized in this browser.
>   If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an
>   uppercase letter.

I'm guessing this has something to do with defining `Home` as a variable rather than a function or class? What am I doing wrong here? How can I get element `<Home></Home>` in the browser without errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With

```
const Home = <Home></Home>;
```

You're trying to render `Home` component which is not defined yet.

Second thing is that you're trying to reassign `Home` which should be declared earlier.

JSX (React) treats upper-first tags as a reference to the variables/classes defined earlier in the scope.

Valid use case can be:

```
const Home = () => <div>hello world</div>;

const AnotherComponent = () => <Home></Home>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined `Home` anywhere to use it as `<Home>`. Further, you are assigning a variable named `Home` while using that variable. If that variable already exists (`<Home>`), then you can't create a variable with that name.

```
const X = 1; // fine
const X = 2; // error
```

`<Home>` means to create an instance of the React class called `Home`, meaning `Home` must already be defined, meaning you can't assign anything to a variable named `Home` because the `Home` variable must already exist.